# How to pass a string array pointer to a new character array? in C

Tags: c, string

I have an array pointer and I try to pass strings of this pointer to a new array. However, I can not print out the new array. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *array[5] = {"may", "june", "july", "august", "september"};
    char buffer[5];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        buffer[i] = *array[i];
        printf(%s , buffer[i]);     
    }
}
```

I can not compile the program because it got error of %s. How can I print out the buffer array like:

may june july august september

without changing it format char buffer[5] which means I do not want to change it to *buffer[5] or anything else. Thank you.

Comment: Enable *compiler warnings* and do not accept code until it compiles without a single warning. You do no need either `stdlib.h` or `string.h` for the code shown.

Comment: The 1st argument to `printf()` had to be a C-"sting', which `%s` is not, but `"%s"` were. Mind the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're wanting to do. You can use strcpy() to copy the contents of one array to another.

```
char* array[5] = {"may", "june", "july", "august", "september"};
char arr[10];

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    strcpy(arr, array[i]);
    printf("%s\n", arr);
}
```

Or if you want to do it like this instead with a 2d char array.

```
char* array[5] = {"may", "june", "july", "august", "september"};
char arr2d[5][10];

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    strcpy(arr2d[i], array[i]);
    printf("%s\n", arr2d[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I can not compile the program because it got error of %s. How can I
>   print out the buffer array like:
>
> ```
>  may june july august september
> ```

Quite simply print out each index of `array`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char *array[] = {"may", "june", "july", "august", "september"};
    int nmembers = sizeof array / sizeof *array;

    for (int i = 0; i < nmembers; i++)
        printf(" %s", array[i]); 
    putchar ('\n');     /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

**note:** do not use *magic numbers* in your code. There is no need. You can compute the number of elements in `array` using `sizeof` (only when `array` is declared within the current scope)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/parraymess
 may june july august september
```

**Why does it work that way?**

`char *array[] = {"...", ...};` declares an *array of pointers to* `char` and each pointer making up the array is initialized to point to the beginning of each *string-literal* used within the initializer., e.g.

```
array[0] = "may";
array[1] = "june";
...
```

Since you have an *array of pointers to* `char`, each element is a *pointer to* `char`, e.g. `char*`. When you access each individual member of an array using `name[..]` the `[..]` acts as a *dereference*. So simply looping over each element `for (int i = 0; i < nmembers; i++)` and then accessing `array[i]` references a pointer (e.g. `char*`) to the beginning of each string that can be used with the `"%s"` format specifier in `printf`.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: The above code is just small sample code in my whole project.  I do need char buffer[5] instead of *array[]. My purpose is to convert from *array to exactly char buffer[5]

Comment: `"september"` will not fit in `char buffer[5];`, you would need at minimum `char buffer[10];` but **never skimp on buffer size**, so `char buffer[32];` would be reasonable. You would rather have a buffer `10,000` characters **too long** than ***1 character too short***. With a properly sized buffer, it is simply `strcpy (buffer, array[i]);` or simply `int j = 0; for (; array[i][j]; j++) buffer[j] = array[i][j]; buffer[j] = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store a string in space of a `char`. You can either have an array of `char *` for a string (and allocate memory dynalically) or you can store the strings in a two-dimensional char array e.g.:

```
char buffer[5][MAX_LEN];
```

and then you may copy strings from `array` to `buffer` using either `strcpy` or by writing your own function.

Comment: They are only storing a char in the space of a char. The problem is lack of a space for, and lack of *nul-termination* -- and the `printf` inside the loop.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Perhaps I was not clear, but that's what I meant by "string in space for char".

Comment: That's OK, the code along with the question wasn't exactly clear either `:)` (no ding)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *array[5] = {"may", "june", "july", "august", "september"};
    char *buffer[5];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        buffer[i] = strdup(array[i]);
        printf("%s ", buffer[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You need `buffer` to be an array of `5` pointers to char. You have declared `buffer` as a `char` array of size `5`, this will not be large enough to hold strings larger than `4` chars (mind the trailing `\0`).

`strdup` is a function which takes a c-string, and writes that string to some space it allocates by calling `malloc` and returns a pointer to that new space.

If you really need `buffer` be a `char` array, you should make sure it can hold the longest string you want to write to it *and* a trailing `\0`. Then you could use the `strcpy` function to write data to `buffer`. Like so:

```
int main(void) {
    char *array[5] = {"may", "june", "july", "august", "september"};
    char buffer[12];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
        strcpy(buffer, array[i]);
        printf("%s ", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```